# Sometimes Restart button not working on mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sometimes the restart button not working only on the mobile platform but the Unity editor works fine. I am using Unity 2021.3 version. This happens rarely and only on mobile. I already added my all scenes in build settings. This is my code:

```
public void Restart()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

Comment: I doubt it is the method not working selectively ... but rather the method not being called. Are you sure the button is reacting to your tap and not maybe overlaid by any other raycast blocking UI item?